# Show Message if VSTO Runtime is not installed (Visual Studio Installer)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, vsto

I am creating msi setup for Excel Addin, I want setup to give error message to user if VSTO2010 runtime is not found. I have added below launch conditions and registry search but its not working.
[image: Requirements & Launch Conditions]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting the key information to be in the 32-bit registry or the 64-bit part?

Comment: Both, I want to create a setup that should work on both x64 & x86...

Comment: @adit: Leave aside the two builds. Is that registry data in the 64-bit registry AND the 32-bit registry? When you look in the registry and see the key data are you looking in the 64-bit native registry or the WoW6432 registry?